# Back button HTML-page access with JAVA

Tags: java, html

I want to activate the back button of the HTML-browser. with a JAVA command not Javascript.
does anyone know how?

Comment: Got the answer its just .back();

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about an applet: I assume you would have to use the [netscape.javascript packages](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html) to hit the JS API for it.

If you are talking about server side Java, then you have no way to trigger the back functionality. The closest you could come would be to read the referer (warning: Optional! Sometimes forged! Make sure it is a URI on your domain!) and issue a Location header to redirect forwards to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Java runs on the server.  JavaScript runs on the client.  You could have a JSP output JavaScript which is then run at client time in the browser.

Comment: Java can run in the browser via `<applet>` or `<object>`

Comment: Yes.  But an applet can't access the browser history directly either.  The location header is an interesting approach.  That happens on page load so it's different than the standard "how do I use the back button answer" - interesting approach though!

Comment: Eve: isn't that back() JavaScript?